Why does breakpoint() not work in jupyter lab?
Title says it all, I'm running jupyterlab with what should be default settings & the python builtin breakpoint() does nothing... It works fine in ipython/python though. Am I missing something?

For those ending up here who may be interested in the practical options available and not the why, see 'How to add a breakpoint in Jupyter notebook?' and 'What is the right way to debug in iPython notebook?'.
